# How to plot multiple variables on y-axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a text file containing data like this:

```
   A             C             G    class     phylum       order
-0.000187   -0.219166   1.693306 Chordata   Monotremata   Mammalia  
0.015664    -0.264506   1.482692 Chordata   Batidoidimorpha   Chondrichthyes    
-0.404323   0.219374    2.230190 Platyhelminthes   Cyclophyllidea   Cestoda
```

but of course it has a lot of rows. I want to plot this data in such a way that all the classes are plotted on the x-axis, each one of them has the A, C and G value plotted as geom_point, and that these points are connected using a line with a specific color depending on A,C or G.
I managed to do this by using the plot and par functions, but now I want to do it using the ggplot library.

Comment: your question is not clear. What are the lines supposed to connect? Are there supposed to be different lines for each column: A, C, & G? It may help if you post the code you currently have so people can translate. Also, try posting some sample data that others can use in their R session with something like `dput(head(x,10))`. How do `phylum` and `order` fit into the graph, if at all?

Answer (score 10):

The specifics of your question are a bit unclear, but the general approach to plotting multiple variables in one plot with `ggplot` graphics is to `melt()` the `data.frame()` first. I didn't follow how the points and lines are supposed to fit into your graph, but here's an approach that uses the `colour` parameter to plot the columns `A`, `C`, and `G` by `class` on the x-axis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), g = rnorm(10), class = sample(letters[20:23], 10, TRUE))
df.m <- melt(df)
ggplot(df.m, aes(class, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I wanted to plot.

The answer is, you need a **NEW** column, which can be set as the group interaction. Here, I created a column called V1, which designates which letter, each letter belongs too, then use `aes(group=interaction(variable.factor, new.factor)`. In this example case, the column 'V1' is arbitrary.

```
  class variable       value V1
1      u        a  0.77041380  a
2      v        a  0.09461429  a
3      t        a  0.22704242  a
4      w        a -0.21501380  a
5      w        a -0.48246983  a
6      v        a  1.69609897  a
7      w        a -0.38847860  a
8      t        a  2.45669883  a
9      t        a  0.24774451  a
10     u        a  0.04195110  a
11     u        c  0.57444553  c
12     v        c  0.73172047  c
13     t        c -1.59409421  c
14     w        c -0.12679464  c
15     w        c  0.19424856  c
16     v        c -1.28742724  c
17     w        c -1.12103626  c
18     t        c -0.57090558  c
19     t        c  0.53798077  c
20     u        c -0.47777022  c
21     u        g -0.91249913  g
22     v        g -1.49256508  g
23     t        g -1.77449710  g
24     w        g  0.71426647  g
25     w        g  0.79678361  g
26     v        g -1.28814106  g
27     w        g -1.04701972  g
28     t        g  0.07309817  g
29     t        g  2.03606615  g
30     u        g  1.76030312  g
```

slightly modiftiyng the ggplot code above:

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(class, value, colour = variable, group = interaction(V1, variable))) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

This results in a line which connects each letter, across each class (from the above answer). (sorry low rep, please follow link)

[letters connected by line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx26a.jpg)

If you want to separate the lines, use `position=position_dodge()`

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(class, value, colour = variable, group = interaction(V1, variable))) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

[letters connected by line with jitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp6SE.jpg)

The take away here is you need a factor for `group=interaction()` which is separate from, and spans across your x axis.